# Understanding the code of partial() function in pryr package (R language)?

Tags: r, functional-programming

I know how partial function works. However, when I look at the source code of partial(), I don't quite understand how it works. Could anyone tell me how each line works?

```
> partial
function (`_f`, ..., .env = parent.frame(), .lazy = TRUE) 
{
    stopifnot(is.function(`_f`))
    if (.lazy) {
        fcall <- substitute(`_f`(...))
    }
    else {
        fcall <- make_call(substitute(`_f`), .args = list(...))
    }
    fcall[[length(fcall) + 1]] <- quote(...)
    args <- list(... = quote(expr = ))
    make_function(args, fcall, .env)
}
<environment: namespace:pryr>
```

What is `_f`? Why using substitute() in this way

```
substitute(`_f`(...))
```

What is this?

```
quote(expr = )
```

Why is the following line necessary?

```
fcall[[length(fcall) + 1]] <- quote(...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some operations in R don't look like function calls, but they are. For example, 3+4 can also be written as `+`(3,4). In this case, since the partial function works by pre-filling in arguments, the "substitute" here works by substituting any variables found in the environment into "...".

quote() works by capturing the action

Seems like the fcall line is used to maintain what was originally placed into the partial call

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation! how to interpret the expr= in quote? Why is it necessary?